# Tail bound for Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, gaussian

Let $t > 0$ and $X$ a random variable from Standard Gaussian Distribution. We then have the following tail bound

$$
P(X \geq t ) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{t} ^{\infty} \exp \left( \frac{-x^2} {2} \right) \ d x \leq \frac{1} {t\sqrt {2\pi}} \exp \left( \frac{-t^2} {2} \right).
$$

I would like to derive the following, generalized tail bound where $X$ is drawn according to a Normal Distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma > 0$:

$$
P(X \geq \mu + \sigma t  ) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}  \int_{\mu +\sigma t} ^{\infty} \exp \left( \frac{-(x - \mu)^2} {2\sigma ^2} \right) \ d x \leq \frac{1} {t\sqrt {2\pi}} \exp \left( \frac{-t^2} {2} \right).
$$

I came up with the following:

**Proof.** Let $z := \sigma x + \mu$. Then $ \frac{d}{dx} z = \sigma.$ So we get by substitution

$$
\int_{\mu +\sigma t} ^{\infty} \exp \left( \frac{-(z - \mu)^2} {2\sigma ^2} \right) \ d z = \int_{t} ^{\infty} \sigma\exp \left( \frac{-x^2} {2} \right) \ d x ,
$$
which, together with the original tail bound, yields the second bound. qed.

I am not very accustomed to probability theory and integrals. Can anyone point out mistakes that I made or can one actually generalize the bound that easily? Also, if you think one needs to operate a bit more carefully, let me know.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't the bound be independent of the variable $x$?

Comment: @AndreasLenz Thanks, that was a typo. I fixed it now.

Comment: Might be actually easier to note that $Y=\frac{X -\mu}{\sigma}$ follows $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution and your probability is exactly $\mathbb P(Y \ge t)$

Comment: @DominikKutek Oh well, that even seems like an easier argument, thank you!